# call php function and using global variable inside php function

Tags: php, html

I want to enable a control based on the user input.. if user click yes i want to display it else hide it.. so i called a function and assigned value based on that i want to display the control..

This is the php Function

```
<?
$hscEnable="false";
function HSControl($val) 
{
    if($val=="yes")
    {
        return("true");
    }
    else
    {
        return("false");    
    }
}
?>
```

I have called it from html form

```
<input type="radio" name="twelthStudiedStatus" value="no" id="twelthStudiedStatus_1" checked onClick= <? $hscEnable=HSControl("no"); ?> >

  <? if($hscEnable=="true"){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td>Percentage :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="twelthPercentage" /></td>
  </tr>
  <?  } ?>
```

Comment: PHP - Server-side, HTML/JS - Client-side..

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better?! What exactly do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: `return("true")` seems strange for me.

Comment: @tuxtimo i don't know ajax. so only i'm using php.. Even though in php i'm just learning..

Comment: So read my answer below .. there I've written, that the only one solution without Ajax is to reload the page and generate the new HTML page (simply echo in PHP) with your desired controls via PHP..

Comment: what global variable????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HSControl(value) {
        document.getElementById("twelthPercentage").style.display = (value == 'no') ? "none" : "block";
    }
</script>
<input type="radio" name="twelthStudiedStatus" value="no" id="twelthStudiedStatus_1" checked onClick=HSControl('no')>
<input type="radio" name="twelthStudiedStatus" value="yes" id="twelthStudiedStatus_1" onClick=HSControl('yes')>
<tr>
    <td>Percentage :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="twelthPercentage" name="twelthPercentage" hidden/></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a PHP function directly over JavaScript, because your PHP is on the server and the JavaScript is on the client on which the webpage is called.
You can solve this by using **Ajax**. Or if you just want to disable or enable a control - you can directly use JavaScript instead of PHP!

Without Ajax you cannot execute PHP without a server request. So another solution can be to reload the whole page and send the new page, with the new controls, over PHP back to the client!

Look at this image to understand the logic of "php: server, javascript: client"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call server side functions using AJAX, jQuery makes this pretty easy.

See, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/